# HTACCESS directories redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I'm trying to redirect the address
 
**www.example.com/tops/articles/first_article**

to the address 
**www.example.com/tops/test1.php?name=first_article**

also to redirect the address 
**www.example.com/tops/galleries/first_gallery**

to the address 
**www.example.com/tops/test2.php?name=first_gallery**

and all other addresses like 
**www.example.com/tops/first_page** 

to 
**www.example.com/tops/page.php?name=first_page**

The following htaccess file is giving me a redirect loop.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^/tops/articles/(.+)$  /tops/test1.php?name=$1  [L]

RewriteRule ^/tops/galleries/(.+)$  /tops/test2.php?name=$1  [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ ./page.php?name=$1
```

Doe's anyone has any idea why is that?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please tell me what is missing so I will know for next time.

Comment: Specially the first slash for the first subdirectory in the pattern `/tops`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tops/articles/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)/?$   http://www.example.com/tops/test1.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tops/galleries/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)/?$   http://www.example.com/tops/test2.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tops/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_.]+)/?$   http://www.example.com/page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Replace all 3 rules with these rules.

**UPDATED** for all characters:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tops/articles/([^/]*)/?$   http://www.example.com/tops/test1.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tops/galleries/([^/]*)/?$   http://www.example.com/tops/test2.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tops/([^/]*)/?$   http://www.example.com/tops/page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

.htaccess should be in root directory If it is in `/tops` directory, try removing it from the pattern and the substitution URL.

Comment: this is not per my requirements.

Comment: It is per your requirements!

Comment: The problem is that I didn't specify my requirement as good as I should.
It needs to refer all charecters instead of just the one you supplied.
The other thing I had to mention is that the htaccess file is sitting under http://www.example.com/tops

Comment: @Amit If .* is used instead of what I wrote, the slash will be included and that will not work. That's the reason to use certain characters only. Nevertheless, I  can update the answer if you tell me what are the other characters you need. Thank's for the clarification anyway.

Comment: @Amit You should move it to the root directory. You need it in the root directory for the last rule to work, unless page.php is not in the roor directory. It seems it is. Try to explain it further in the question.

Comment: I'm using charecters in other languages (hebrew, arabic, hindu) that can't be entered in the reg expression. that is why I'm using (.+)
Look at the the answer I've been able to come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Does `page.php` exist in the root directory (or any other non `/tops/` directory for that matter)?

If not, then that is probably your problem. You should change your last rule to something like:

```
RewriteRule ^tops/(.*)$ /tops/page.php?name=$1
```

Comment: the third rule works perfectly. I have no problem with it. The problem is with the first and second rules.

Comment: @Amit Aisikowitz You can try it without the slash: `^tops/` instead of `^/tops/`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got it working.

Thought I share it so if anyone every search for this question he will find it.

Here is the code that workd:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$ ./test1.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^galleries/(.+)$ ./test2.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ ./page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Enjoy !